# Python - issue with filtering DataFrame in loop

Tags: python, loops

In my project I'm creating few excel files. After that I want to paste filtered `DataFrame` base on settings.
Due to unknown reason filtering data gives me empty `DataFrame`. If I launch code without loop then it works. It works also if I type value for "SAP_Plant_value".

Any advice what I do wrong?

```
for index, row in bi_df.iterrows():
    file_name = row["File_Name"]
    try:        
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(reports_path + file_name, data_only=True)
        materials = wb["Materials"]
        SAP_Plant_value = row["SAP Plant"]
        erp_value = row["ERP"]
        print(f"SAP Plant value: {SAP_Plant_value}")  # Debugging print
        if erp_value == "BKP":
            # Check unique values in the "Plant" column
            unique_plants = set(BKPsheetPD["Plant"])
            print(f"Unique plants in BKPsheetPD: {unique_plants}")  # Debugging print

            # Filter the data
            BKPsheetPDfilter = BKPsheetPD[BKPsheetPD["Plant"] == SAP_Plant_value]
            print(BKPsheetPDfilter)  # Debugging print
            BKPsheetPDfilter = list(dataframe_to_rows(BKPsheetPDfilter, index=False, header=False))
            for r_idx, row in enumerate(BKPsheetPDfilter, 3):
                for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
                    materials.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=value)
                    # Updating status in "Cover"        
                    cover_sheet = template["Cover"]
                    cover_sheet["C49"] = "Y"
                    template.save(template_path)
        else:
            print("S4 not available yet")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

```
SAP Plant value: 1733
Unique plants in BKPsheetPD: {'1109', '1623', '1733', '1105'}
Empty DataFrame
```

Comment: You may need to do `BKPsheetPDfilter = BKPsheetPD[BKPsheetPD["Plant"].astype(int) == SAP_Plant_value]`

Comment: Indeed it worked in this way. Thanks!